# Extract Data from .PDF files

Tags: c#

I need to extract data from .PDF files and load it in to SQL 2008. Can any one tell me how to proceed??

[image: This is how the data looks]

Comment: **Step one: Search.** This question gets asked literally 3 times a day here. And *inevitably* someone answers with "use iTextSharp". I'm too tired of it to even do that anymore.

Comment: @Cody Gray .....I did but but i was not able 2 solve the issue as u said i am also tired of the answer use iTextSharp......which did not help me :(

Comment: @ramesh - And why do you think asking the same question again will change the answer? If you have more issues, ask about those.

Comment: @ramesh: So, comment that on the answer to the other question. Then edit your original question to clarify *why*, specifically, iTextSharp didn't work for you. That will automatically bump the question back to the top of the queue so that others will see it again. That's not a good reason to open a duplicate question. And look what's happening. Someone *else* is replying to use iTextSharp, because you didn't explain *why* you couldn't use it.

Comment: I tried ItextSharp but it did not work, basically almost all the functions in it are to create and edit a PDF doc but not to read the data.....

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a PDF library such as [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to extract the data from the PDF.

At this point, you have the data and can insert it into a database.

Comment: can you provide me a sample code??

Comment: @ramesh - Whatever I could post will not work for your specific situation, since every PDF will have different structure. I suggest downloading, installing and experimenting with iTextSharp. Find out how the PDF is structured and how to get to the different parts.

Comment: I tried ItextSharp but it did not work, basically almost all the functions in it are to create and edit a PDF doc but not to read the data.....

Answer (score 0):

Text extraction works good with iText until you don't have a requirement to extract text from columns instead of rows (like Adobe Reader and Foxit Reader do when you copy the text from a PDF document. To extract text column by column the tool need to calculate a position and coordinates for text on a page

The commercial tool [ByteScout PDF Extractor SDK](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfextractorsdk/index.html) capable of doing such text extraction with both row by row and column by column modes for text extraction (or can simply extract data as the structured XML)

**DISCLAIMER:** I work for ByteScout currently